# Create subsets of Item objects

Tags: java

hey guys i have class Item which i use to create Item objects

```
 public class Item {

 private String id; 
 private int count;
 private String  name;


public int getcount()
{
   return this.count; 
}

public Item(String name)
 {
     this.name=name;
     this.id = "";

 }



public Item(String id, String name)
 {
     this.name=name;
   this.id=id;

 }

public Item(int count)
{
    this.count=count;
}

public String getItemName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public String getItemId()
{
    return this.id;
}

public Item returnItems(ItemList itemset)
{
    Item item=null;

    return item;
}

}
```

And i have ItemList class that stores List of items. Here am adding List of item objects

```
public  class ItemList implements Iterable<Item> 
{

  private List<Item> hold=new ArrayList<Item>();



  ItemList(Item item)
{


  this.hold.add(item); 
}

ItemList() {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}


public List<Item> getItemSet()
{
    return this.hold;

}


public void addItems(Item item)
{
    //hold = new ArrayList<Item>();
    this.hold.add(item);
}


@Override
public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
     Iterator<Item> item = hold.iterator();
    return item; 
}



}
```

Supose  initailly i add I1,I2,I3 item obects to Itemlist as follows

```
 {I1}
 {I2}
 {I3}
```

now i want to create a subsets of Item objects as follows and add to ItemList where each subset will contain 2 Items

```
     {I1 I2}
     {I1 I3}
     {I2 I3}
```

Please help in creating a subset
 Later i even want have subsets of 2 Items or more
 I want to write a function that will help me to create subsets of n  items
 Please help

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that you API for ItemList class will not help you to achieve your goal. 
What you need is to work with [Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html), in order to work with "Set theory" API 
(i.e intersection, union, etc..) 
You ItemList class probably should have an "asSet" method conerting the ItemList to Set. 
You will need to implement a "PowerSet" calculation in order to get all possible sub sets of items. 
Implementing this using Set API will be easier for you than not using it. 
You can also use some open source from the internet - for example, I googled now, and found [this](http://code.google.com/p/jannocessor/source/browse/jannocessor-collections/src/main/java/org/jannocessor/collection/impl/PowerLinkedHashSet.java?spec=svnc1d17cc8acc5f76a395c9292630ad00ca69c524d&r=c1d17cc8acc5f76a395c9292630ad00ca69c524d) - 
Looked at the interface of PowerSet that the class this URL directs to implements.